# MySQL. 8.0.19. Best index to match given query

Tags: mysql

thank you in advance.

Im trying to improve my query performance, but stuck in such situation:

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_purchases`
(
    `id`        BIGINT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id`   INT         NOT NULL,
    `date`      DATETIME    NOT NULL,
    `status`    VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `purchase`  BIGINT      NOT NULL,
    `cashback`  BIGINT      NULL DEFAULT -1,
    `coupon_id` INT         NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `user_status_key` (`user_id`, `status`),
    KEY `user_key` (`user_id`),
    KEY `status_key` (`status`)
);
```

Table has many historical data about user purchases

To get all i need i execute such query:

```
SELECT id FROM user_purchases p
WHERE p.user_id = 1
  AND p.status IN ('PROCESSED', 'FAILED', 'CANCELLED')
  AND p.id < 400
  AND p.coupon_id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But in situations, where user have thousands of purchases in that statuses it takes too long time.

Does i choose best indexes, or i can change them to other to make this query execute faster?

Result for explain query:

```
select_type - SIMPLE
type - range
select_type - simple
POSSIBLE_KEYS - PRIMARY,user_status_key,status_key,user_key
key - PRIMARY
key_len - 8
ref - null
rows - 8347239
filtered - 0.01
Extra - Using where; Backward index scan
```

If i use force index (user_status_key) result is better

```
select_type - SIMPLE
type - range
select_type - simple
POSSIBLE_KEYS - user_status_key
key - user_status_key
key_len - 270
ref - null
rows - 55324
filtered - 10
Extra - Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

Will i speed up query more by use of other indexes?

Comment: the `p.id < 400` condition seems strange; can you explain what it is for?  also, the `key_len - 270` seems impossible; please show your real table (ideally the complete output of `show create table user_purchases`) or your real explain

Comment: does forcing the `user_key` index instead help?

Comment: output from show create (2 parts to match comment characters limit)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `user_purchases`
(
    `id`        bigint                                                       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id`   int                                                          NOT NULL,
    `date`      datetime                                                     NOT NULL,
    `status`    varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `purchase`  bigint                                                       NOT NULL,
    `cashback`  bigint DEFAULT '-1',
    `coupon_id` int    DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `user_key` (`user_id`),
    KEY `status_key` (`status`),
    KEY `user_status_key` (`user_id`, `status`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 17203377
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: p.id using for pagination on client side, cant use offset cuz if user make some purchases in over window offset can give same row twice between executions

Comment: user_key index helps same as user_status_key. There are too many purchases in other statuses, and a big dataset in historycal

Comment: do you always select those three statuses?  what percentage of rows have one of those statuses?

Comment: yes, only those three statuses. For given user count(1) now is -> CANCELLED,8 FAILED,8401 PROCESSED,13761 CURRENT,1

Comment: Hmm.  I would have expected the user_key index to do better than the user_status_key, since status is not excluding many records.  That makes my answer not likely to help.

Comment: maybe its my fault, i executed exaplain with your query now and it works great - user_status_key,262,"const,statuses.status",10,3.33,Using index condition; Using where. "same as status" - 39840 rows for status user_key and 58043 for player_status_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user_status_key index has user_id, status, and id; you are selecting a single user_id, three different statuses, and a range of ids.  Sometimes where you have multiple different values to look for in a middle part of the index, it helps to specify them via a join rather than an `in` condition.  Give this a try:

```
SELECT straight_join id
FROM (SELECT 'PROCESSED' status UNION ALL SELECT 'FAILED' UNION ALL SELECT 'CANCELLED') statuses
JOIN user_purchases p USE INDEX (user_status_key) ON p.user_id = 1 AND p.status = statuses.status AND p.id < 400
WHERE p.coupon_id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Would love to know how much difference this made (in time, not the explain numbers)

Comment: From 0.32s to 0.0055s

Answer (score 2):

While `KEY` does in fact create a unique index, the problem with your design is that you have separate indexes. Two indexes on A and B are not the same as one index on (A, B). As a consequence, database still has to do separate seeks/scans.

To speed up your query, you want to have an index that contains all your `WHERE` conditions, at least up to the point where the rest is just up to a few records. In addition, you might want to take advantage of the index being ordered in the same way as your `ORDER BY`. So that would be something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON user_purchases (
    user_id, id DESC, status, coupon_id
)
```

Note that indexes are left-associative, so if columns of index A begin with all columns of index B, then B is redundant. But to optimize that, you would need to explain the reasons why you designed your schema like that.